# Mail.app how to archive messages with delete key?

Tags: macos, mail.app, mojave, gmail

Recently I have noticed that Mail.app on Mojave is sending discarded messages to the trash instead of archive.  I have set the preference "Move discarded messages into archive", but that doesn't seem to make a difference.  The user guide says this setting is for swip guestures, but I was hoping it would apply to the delete key as well.

On the toolbar, I have two separate buttons for Delete and Archive.  Both of these buttons work correctly, but I like to discard messages using the delete (backspace) key.

I did figure out that setting Trash Mailbox to None will effectively make all discarded messages go to archive.  But this makes it impossible to trash a message.  I want the delete key to archive and I want the trash button to trash.

There is a menu item to Archive, but Sys Prefs does not allow assigning a custom shortcut for the delete key with no modifier.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: try creating a custom shortcut in System Preference according to, in Mail app, Message menu-> Archive. Also, You can swipe left on a Mac!! pardon because I chuckled. Swipe on the message with two fingers. You should see a archive box if  these settings are in place.

Comment: Oh do you mean swiping with a trackpad? I forgot about that since I use a trackball. Custom shortcut is a good idea, I will try that.

Comment: System Prefs won't let you assign a shortcut to the delete (backspace) key

Comment: @ankii you're right, the swipe guesture does respect this setting. But I prefer the keyboard.

Comment: I asked this question 3 months ago. The other one should be a duplicate!